# How to create a grand total from cumulative values

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have created a report that shows the cumulative totals for each loss month - when a claim was opened and closed.  The image below might help explain this a bit better:

[image: triangle report]

The y-axis the the month of the loss date - and the x-axis shows the months the claim was either opened or closed.  And it is a cumulative total going left to right.

For instance, in Jan. 2014 - there were five total claims opened and one claim that was closed.  Then in Feb. 2014 - two more claims were opened while a second claim was closed.

The yellow-highlighted cell in the image is the value that I am having trouble calculating.  To get the total for the individual loss months - I used a windows function to get the max value and partitioned by year, claim month, and claim status -

```
MAX( ClaimCount ) OVER (PARTITION BY Year, ClaimMonth, ClaimStatus)
```

Unfortunately for me, I have been unable to figure out how to calculate the grand total for the total number of claims ( closed & total ).

Below is sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE #claimcount
(
    Year INT NULL,
    ClaimStatus VARCHAR (25) NULL,
    LossMonth DATE NULL,
    ClaimMonth DATE NULL,
    ClaimCount INT NULL,
    ClaimTotalPerLossMonth INT NULL,
    ClaimTotalPerClaimMonth INT NULL,
    ClaimCountPerLossYear INT NULL
);
INSERT INTO #claimcount
(
    Year,
    ClaimStatus,
    LossMonth,
    ClaimMonth,
    ClaimCount,
    ClaimTotalPerLossMonth,
    ClaimTotalPerClaimMonth,
    ClaimCountPerLossYear
)
VALUES
(2014, 'Closed', '20140131', '20140131', 1, 7, 1, NULL),
(2014, 'Total', '20140131', '20140131', 5, 7, 5, NULL),
(2014, 'Closed', '20140131', '20140228', 2, 7, 2, NULL),
(2014, 'Total', '20140131', '20140228', 7, 7, 9, NULL),
(2014, 'Closed', '20140131', '20140331', 5, 7, 6, NULL),
(2014, 'Total', '20140131', '20140331', 7, 7, 11, NULL),
(2014, 'Closed', '20140131', '20140430', 5, 7, 8, NULL),
(2014, 'Total', '20140131', '20140430', 7, 7, 16, NULL),
(2014, 'Closed', '20140131', '20140531', 5, 7, 9, NULL),
(2014, 'Total', '20140131', '20140531', 7, 7, 33, NULL),
(2014, 'Closed', '20140131', '20140630', 5, 7, 15, NULL),
(2014, 'Total', '20140131', '20140630', 7, 7, 54, NULL),
(2014, 'Closed', '20140131', '20140731', 5, 7, 23, NULL),
(2014, 'Total', '20140131', '20140731', 7, 7, 78, NULL),
(2014, 'Closed', '20140131', '20140831', 6, 7, 48, NULL),
(2014, 'Total', '20140131', '20140831', 7, 7, 109, NULL),
(2014, 'Closed', '20140131', '20140930', 6, 7, 78, NULL),
(2014, 'Total', '20140131', '20140930', 7, 7, 136, NULL),
(2014, 'Closed', '20140131', '20141031', 7, 7, 94, NULL),
(2014, 'Total', '20140131', '20141031', 7, 7, 163, NULL),
(2014, 'Closed', '20140131', '20141130', 7, 7, 110, NULL),
(2014, 'Total', '20140131', '20141130', 7, 7, 187, NULL),
(2014, 'Closed', '20140131', '20141231', 7, 7, 128, NULL),
(2014, 'Total', '20140131', '20141231', 7, 7, 209, NULL),
(2014, 'Closed', '20140131', '20150131', 7, 7, 144, NULL),
(2014, 'Total', '20140131', '20150131', 7, 7, 240, NULL),
(2014, 'Closed', '20140131', '20150228', 7, 7, 167, NULL),
(2014, 'Total', '20140131', '20150228', 7, 7, 280, NULL),
(2014, 'Closed', '20140131', '20150331', 7, 7, 201, NULL),
(2014, 'Total', '20140131', '20150331', 7, 7, 321, NULL),
(2014, 'Closed', '20140131', '20150430', 7, 7, 231, NULL),
(2014, 'Total', '20140131', '20150430', 7, 7, 360, NULL),
(2014, 'Closed', '20140131', '20150531', 7, 7, 251, NULL),
(2014, 'Total', '20140131', '20150531', 7, 7, 386, NULL),
(2014, 'Closed', '20140131', '20150630', 7, 7, 283, NULL),
(2014, 'Total', '20140131', '20150630', 7, 7, 422, NULL),
(2014, 'Closed', '20140131', '20150731', 7, 7, 317, NULL),
(2014, 'Total', '20140131', '20150731', 7, 7, 452, NULL),
(2014, 'Closed', '20140131', '20150831', 7, 7, 346, NULL),
(2014, 'Total', '20140131', '20150831', 7, 7, 475, NULL),
(2014, 'Closed', '20140131', '20150930', 7, 7, 378, NULL),
(2014, 'Total', '20140131', '20150930', 7, 7, 486, NULL),
(2014, 'Closed', '20140131', '20151031', 7, 7, 405, NULL),
(2014, 'Total', '20140131', '20151031', 7, 7, 496, NULL),
(2014, 'Closed', '20140131', '20151130', 7, 7, 426, NULL),
(2014, 'Total', '20140131', '20151130', 7, 7, 501, NULL),
(2014, 'Closed', '20140131', '20151231', 7, 7, 448, NULL),
(2014, 'Total', '20140131', '20151231', 7, 7, 509, NULL),
(2014, 'Closed', '20140228', '20140131', 0, 2, 1, NULL),
(2014, 'Total', '20140228', '20140131', 0, 2, 5, NULL),
(2014, 'Closed', '20140228', '20140228', 0, 2, 2, NULL),
(2014, 'Total', '20140228', '20140228', 2, 2, 9, NULL),
(2014, 'Closed', '20140228', '20140331', 1, 2, 6, NULL),
(2014, 'Total', '20140228', '20140331', 2, 2, 11, NULL),
(2014, 'Closed', '20140228', '20140430', 2, 2, 8, NULL),
(2014, 'Total', '20140228', '20140430', 2, 2, 16, NULL),
(2014, 'Closed', '20140228', '20140531', 2, 2, 9, NULL),
(2014, 'Total', '20140228', '20140531', 2, 2, 33, NULL),
(2014, 'Closed', '20140228', '20140630', 2, 2, 15, NULL),
(2014, 'Total', '20140228', '20140630', 2, 2, 54, NULL),
(2014, 'Closed', '20140228', '20140731', 2, 2, 23, NULL),
(2014, 'Total', '20140228', '20140731', 2, 2, 78, NULL),
(2014, 'Closed', '20140228', '20140831', 2, 2, 48, NULL),
(2014, 'Total', '20140228', '20140831', 2, 2, 109, NULL),
(2014, 'Closed', '20140228', '20140930', 2, 2, 78, NULL),
(2014, 'Total', '20140228', '20140930', 2, 2, 136, NULL),
(2014, 'Closed', '20140228', '20141031', 2, 2, 94, NULL),
(2014, 'Total', '20140228', '20141031', 2, 2, 163, NULL),
(2014, 'Closed', '20140228', '20141130', 2, 2, 110, NULL),
(2014, 'Total', '20140228', '20141130', 2, 2, 187, NULL),
(2014, 'Closed', '20140228', '20141231', 2, 2, 128, NULL),
(2014, 'Total', '20140228', '20141231', 2, 2, 209, NULL),
(2014, 'Closed', '20140228', '20150131', 2, 2, 144, NULL),
(2014, 'Total', '20140228', '20150131', 2, 2, 240, NULL),
(2014, 'Closed', '20140228', '20150228', 2, 2, 167, NULL),
(2014, 'Total', '20140228', '20150228', 2, 2, 280, NULL),
(2014, 'Closed', '20140228', '20150331', 2, 2, 201, NULL),
(2014, 'Total', '20140228', '20150331', 2, 2, 321, NULL),
(2014, 'Closed', '20140228', '20150430', 2, 2, 231, NULL),
(2014, 'Total', '20140228', '20150430', 2, 2, 360, NULL),
(2014, 'Closed', '20140228', '20150531', 2, 2, 251, NULL),
(2014, 'Total', '20140228', '20150531', 2, 2, 386, NULL),
(2014, 'Closed', '20140228', '20150630', 2, 2, 283, NULL),
(2014, 'Total', '20140228', '20150630', 2, 2, 422, NULL),
(2014, 'Closed', '20140228', '20150731', 2, 2, 317, NULL),
(2014, 'Total', '20140228', '20150731', 2, 2, 452, NULL),
(2014, 'Closed', '20140228', '20150831', 2, 2, 346, NULL),
(2014, 'Total', '20140228', '20150831', 2, 2, 475, NULL),
(2014, 'Closed', '20140228', '20150930', 2, 2, 378, NULL),
(2014, 'Total', '20140228', '20150930', 2, 2, 486, NULL),
(2014, 'Closed', '20140228', '20151031', 2, 2, 405, NULL),
(2014, 'Total', '20140228', '20151031', 2, 2, 496, NULL),
(2014, 'Closed', '20140228', '20151130', 2, 2, 426, NULL),
(2014, 'Total', '20140228', '20151130', 2, 2, 501, NULL),
(2014, 'Closed', '20140228', '20151231', 2, 2, 448, NULL),
(2014, 'Total', '20140228', '20151231', 2, 2, 509, NULL);

SELECT Year,
       ClaimStatus,
       LossMonth,
       MAX ( ClaimTotalPerLossMonth )
FROM #claimcount
GROUP BY Year,
         ClaimStatus,
         LossMonth;

SELECT *
FROM #claimcount;

DROP TABLE #claimcount;
```

Comment: Have a look at `ROLLUP` and or `GROUPING SETS` (seems the latter is more appropriate here).

Comment: Thanks - looking at GROUPING SETS - seems interesting but I've never used before so I am not at a solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand your question correctly, but maybe you are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT x.Year, x.ClaimStatus, x.LossMonth, 
    SUM(MaxClaimTotalPerLossMonth) AS MaxClaimTotalPerLossMonth
FROM (
    SELECT Year, ClaimStatus, LossMonth,
           MAX ( ClaimTotalPerLossMonth ) AS MaxClaimTotalPerLossMonth
    FROM #claimcount
    GROUP BY Year, ClaimStatus, LossMonth
) x GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((Year, ClaimStatus, LossMonth), (Year, ClaimStatus));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just place what you calculate into a CTE and you can sum that up for the gran total:

```
;with t as(
SELECT Year,
       ClaimStatus,
       LossMonth,
       MAX ( ClaimTotalPerLossMonth )MaxClaims
       , sum(ClaimTotalPerLossMonth)ClaimCountPerLossYear
       , sum(ClaimTotalPerClaimMonth)ClaimTotalPerClaimMonth
       , sum(ClaimCount)ClaimCount
FROM #claimcount
GROUP BY Year,
         ClaimStatus,
         LossMonth
)
select * from t
union all
select 0,'GRAN TOTAL',NULL,sum(MaxClaims),sum(ClaimCountPerLossYear)
    ,sum(ClaimTotalPerClaimMonth),sum(ClaimCount)
from t
```